# How to make sound play only once on mouse over in Processing?

Tags: audio, processing, mouseover

I'm trying to make a sound play when the mouse moves over a button in Processing. Currently, it is playing over and over again because my button class is in the `draw()` function. I understand why this is happening, but I can't think of a way to only play the sound once while still being tied to my `overRect()` function.

main:

```java
import processing.sound.*;

PlayButton playButton;
SoundFile mouseOverSound;
SoundFile clickSound;
color white = color(255); 
color gray = color(241, 241, 241);
PFont verdanabold; 

void setup() 
{
  size(720, 1280);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  rectMode(CENTER);

  verdanabold = createFont("Verdana Bold", 60, true);  
  playButton = new PlayButton();
  mouseOverSound = new SoundFile(this, "mouseover.wav");
  clickSound = new SoundFile(this, "click.mp3");
}

void draw()
{
  background(gray);
  playButton.display(); // draw play button
}
```

playButton class:

```java
class PlayButton // play button
{
  float rectX = width/2; // button x position
  float rectY = height-height/4; // button y position
  int rectWidth = 275; // button width
  int rectHeight = 75; // button height
  boolean rectOver = false; // boolean determining if mouse is over button

  void display() // draws play button and controls its function
  {
    update(mouseX, mouseY);

    if(rectOver) // controls button color when mouse over
    {
      fill(white);
      mouseOverSound.play(); // play mouse over sound
    }
    else
    {
      fill(gray); 
    }

    strokeWeight(5); // button
    stroke(black);
    rect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

    textFont(verdanabold, 48); // button text
    fill(black);
    text("PLAY", rectX, rectY+15);

    if(mousePressed && rectOver) // if mouse over and clicked, change to state 1
    {
      state = 1;
      clickSound.play(); // play click sound
    }
  }

  void update(float x, float y) // determines if mouse is over button using overRect(), changes boolean rectOver accordingly
  {
    if(overRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight))
    {
      rectOver = true;
    }
    else
    {
      rectOver = false; 
    }
  }

  boolean overRect(float rectX, float rectY, int rectWidth, int rectHeight) // compares mouse pos to button pos and returns true if =
  {
     if(mouseX >= rectX-rectWidth/2 && mouseX <= rectX+rectWidth/2 && mouseY >= rectY-rectHeight/2 && mouseY <= rectY+rectHeight/2)
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
Initialized int i = 0. While mouse is over the button, plays sound while i < 1, then increments i by 1 inside the while loop so it stops playing. When mouse is not over the button, i is set back to 0.

Edited playButton class:

```
class HowToButton // how to button
{
  float rectX = width/2; // button x position
  float rectY = height-height/8; // button y position
  int rectWidth = 275; // button width
  int rectHeight = 75; // button height
  boolean rectOver = false; // boolean determining if mouse is over button
  int i = 0;

  void display() // draws how to button and controls its function
  {
    update(mouseX, mouseY);

    if (rectOver) // controls button color when mouse over
    {
      fill(white);
      while(i < 1) // play sound while i < 1
      {
       mouseOverSound.play(); // play mouse over sound
       i++; // increment i so sound only plays once
      }
    }
    else
    {
      fill(gray); 
      i = 0; // set i back to 0 when mouse leaves bounds of button
    }

    strokeWeight(5); // button
    stroke(black);
    rect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

    textFont(verdanabold, 48); // button text
    fill(black);
    text("HOW TO", rectX, rectY+15);

    if(mousePressed && rectOver) // if mouse over and clicked, change to state 2
    {
      state = 2;
      clickSound.play(); // play click sound
    }
  }

  void update(float x, float y) // determines if mouse is over button using overRect(), changes boolean rectOver accordingly
  {
    if(overRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight))
    {
      rectOver = true;
    }
    else
    {
      rectOver = false; 
    }
  }

  boolean overRect(float rectX, float rectY, int rectWidth, int rectHeight) // compares mouse pos to button pos and returns true if =
  {
     if(mouseX >= rectX-rectWidth/2 && mouseX <= rectX+rectWidth/2 && mouseY >= rectY-rectHeight/2 && mouseY <= rectY+rectHeight/2)
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `boolean` variable that indicates whether the sound is already playing. Something like this:

```java
if(mousePressed && rectOver && !alreadyPlaying)
{
  alreadyPlaying = true;
  state = 1;
  clickSound.play(); // play click sound
}
```

In fact, you might be able to use the `state` variable:

```java
if(mousePressed && rectOver && state != 1)
{
  state = 1;
  clickSound.play(); // play click sound
}
```

You could also look into the sound library you're using, it might have a function that tells you whether the sound is already playing, which you could use in the same way.

Comment: That makes sense. I thought of something similar to your idea (but a little less efficient) right before you posted. The state variable actually controls the state of the game this button is for, I just didn't include the entire code since the issue I was having was just with the sound. Thanks!